# What is the appropriate handling of security rules for the value of a Double Child?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Say you have a child called peopleWhoLike that has the form:

```
 "people": {
        "$uid": {
    peopleWhoLike: {
        ChildByAutoID: uid of the user who likes the current user.
       }
    }

   "$uid1” ….
```

////for example

```
“people” : {
 “Cawefaeerfregherthe” : {
   “peopleWhoLike" : {
        "Optional(\"-MDWpTyQjA6a1VzTWvEV\")" : "QqQpDheHC4cC9bs4KtreArFiS8g2",
}
}
```

I know how to target rules for peopleWhoLike, for example giving authorized users access to the node. What I am talking about here is not rules for that node, but rather rules for its value. So in this instance,  in the Double (ChildByAutoID: UID of user who likes logged in user), I need to make a rule that checks who that UID can be. For example only allow write if he is auth.uid

I thought maybe something like this:

```
"peopleWhoLike" : {
    "$peopleWhoLike": { "
       .read": "auth.uid != null", 
         ".write": "$peopleWhoLike == auth.uid" 
              } }
```

In practical terms:

So in practical terms, the user QqQpDheHC4cC9bs4KtreArFiS8g2 wants to like the user Cawefaeerfregherthe. I need a write rule to allow this. I want to make sure that QqQpDheHC4cC9bs4KtreArFiS8g2 is the current user (auth.uid), so I need to make some kind of rule at the Double `(Optional(\"-MDWpTyQjA6a1VzTWvEV\")"` : "QqQpDheHC4cC9bs4KtreArFiS8g2) to see if he is auth.uid – frank timmon just now

Comment: Can you be more specific, what problem you are facing?

Comment: So in practical terms, the user QqQpDheHC4cC9bs4KtreArFiS8g2 wants to like the user Cawefaeerfregherthe. I need a write rule to allow this. I want to make sure that QqQpDheHC4cC9bs4KtreArFiS8g2 is the current user (auth.uid), so I need to make some kind of rule at the Double `(Optional(\"-MDWpTyQjA6a1VzTWvEV\")" : "QqQpDheHC4cC9bs4KtreArFiS8g2)` to see if he is auth.uid